# How should I phrase a résumé if I have an uncertain degree plan?

Tags: cv

I have been working towards a degree in mathematics and in computer science for the last two and a half years. That corresponds to the following bit in my résumé:

> **Education**
>   B.A. in Mathematics (2012 - 2016 expected)
>   B.S. in Computer Science (2012 - 2016 expected)

However, I recently found out that I can graduate next semester with a major in mathematics and a minor in computer science. If that was my plan, I would write this:

> **Education**
>   B.A. in Mathematics (2012 - 2015 expected)
>   Minor: Computer Science

However, at the moment I am undecided about which path I plan to take.

Which should I include in the résumé? I am considering just writing down whichever one would seem more impressive, but I don't want to be deceitful.

Answer (score 3):

Facing an uncertain graduate date is a common issue, particularly for many Ph.D. students who aren't sure exactly when they are going to defend.  The thing that you want in your C.V. is to communicate as clearly as possible what are your skills *and time of availability* to the people considering taking you on for your next career stage after graduation.  Thus, put your current best estimate in; if you want to indicate an option to join a position earlier, put that in as well as an option.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I worded my resume was 
Stating the school you when to, the city,state 
Bachelors of Some Thing 
Additional Fields of Study: Minor in Computer Science and Engineering

In terms of your resume, I would start out stating your revelant course work in a list but make it into a table (hide the borders when your done) that you can hide in MS Word.

After that put your volunteer and work history

after putting that put all the skills and qualifications.

I added something a bit extra which was I speak Chinese (Mandarin, Cantonese), Spanish, Japanese, and English (my second language was English)

Math majors are much needed in CS and in biology. That's a very good path.